# Caching in Openshift Binary Build doesn't work

Tags: docker, openshift

Accorindg to documentation, Openshift binary builds support caching of docker layers.

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/builds.html#no-cache

Using Openshift 3.11

This is sample buildconfig that does not cache docker layers between builds. **I've set explicitly noCache to false to avoid any confusion.** Did not help.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
 name: build-template-binary
labels:
 template: build-template-binary
objects:
 - apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
   kind: BuildConfig
   metadata:
     annotations:
       openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewBuild
     labels:
       build: ${NAME}
     name: ${NAME}
   spec:
     failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 50
     output:
       to:
         kind: ImageStreamTag
         name: ${IMAGE_STREAM_NAME}:latest
     runPolicy: Serial
     source:
       type: Binary
     strategy:
       dockerStrategy:
         noCache: false
     successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 20
parameters:
 - name: NAME
   requied: true
 - name: IMAGE_STREAM_NAME
   required: true
```

Every time I run

```
oc start-build my-build-name --from-dir=. --follow
```

Every single step in my dockerfile gets executed. No caching occurs.

Comment: If you are in a multi node cluster, caching only happens when the build lands on the same node as a previous build. Also note that in OpenShift 4.1, caching doesn't apply in the same way.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton do you know how I can check which node the build is running on or how to force it to run always on the same node?

Comment: "The image cache is no longer shared. When using the host’s docker daemon, images and layers that had been pulled to the host previously could be reused by a subsequent build on that same host. Since builds no longer have access to the host, each build must pull any layers it requires each time the build is run. This helps improve the security posture of builds [...] however it will also increase the time required to execute a build. We will be looking to reintroduce a shared image cache in the future." - https://www.openshift.com/blog/openshift-4-image-builds